# Перестала загружаться виртуальная машина Debian 10 в VirtualBox

Tags: linux, debian, windows-10, virtualbox, wsl

Установил VirtualBox Debian 10, несколько раз нормально её загружал, инсталлировал mysql, git и после этого тоже нормально грузилась.
Потом установил туда Docker and Compos - все прошло вроде нормально, и вот после этого спустя несколько дней пытаюсь загрузить её снова, но она грузится не полностью - запроса логина и пароля нет, а когда я её пытаюсь полностью выключить через меню выдает сообщение-

> "Вы пытаетесь завершить работу гостевой ОС с использованием
> виртуальной кнопки ACPI. В данный момент это не возможно поскольку
> гостевая ОС не использует систему ACPI"

Хотя в настройках ACPI галочка стоит. Вводить с клавиатуры ничего не дает.
Судя по панели VirtualBox запускается постоянно снимок сделанный при первом неудачном запуске.
Не знаю важно ли это, но я ещё установил Docker и на основную ОС (Windows 10) и установил WSL2.
Не пойму что случилось и как это исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фрагмент файла логов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Переустановил VirtualBox, пытаюсь с чистого создать новую виртуальную машину -  после выбора образа ISO для установки и выбора п.м. "Install" вообще ничего не происходит.  При этом в заголовке пишет, что работает и в диспетчере задач не хило ест ресурсов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну а по сети пенгуется? Раз виртуалка работает и жрёт ресурсы - может они и по ip отвечает?

Comment: Стоп. А чё это у тебя `debian10.vdi is ntfs`? Эт как?

Comment: В общем дело было в функции Windows hyperviso, которая включилась при установки Docker, она с VB не дружит, нужно отключать: hypervisorlaunchtype off

Comment: Лучше оформи как ответ.

Comment: Да, так и сделал

Answer (score 1):

Дело было в функции Windows hyperviso, которая включается при установки Docker, она с VB не дружит, её нужно отключить следующей командой - hypervisorlaunchtype off, и перезагрузить ОС, чтобы изменения вступили в силу